# Validar formulario woocommerce desde functions.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Quisiera que los input del formulario del checkout en wordpress se validen con diferentes reglas por ejemplo:

Nombre y apellido: solo acepten letras y acentos
Codigo postal: solo acepte numeros y sean solo 5 su maxlegh
Teléfono: solo numeros

Todo desde el archivo functions.php de wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

una manera en que puedes validar los campos es añadiendo un método a:

```
woocommerce_checkout_process
```

De tal manera que en tu *functions.php* agregues un método, por ejemplo:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'validatePhone');
function validatePhone() {
$billing_phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_phone');

 if (strlen(trim(preg_replace('/^[6789]\d{9}$/', '', $billing_phone))) > 0) {
    wc_add_notice(__('Número telefónico incorrecto.'), 'error');
 }
}
```

Otra manera de realizar por medio del functions.php es que añadas tus propios campos de Woocommerce.

En relación a tu nueva pregunta @Walworth para validar solo letras puedes cambiar la expresión regular o utilizar el método *[ctype_alpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)* ctype_alpha retorna un valor TRUE si su argumento es una cadena de texto si aún así decides utilizar una expresión regular puedes utilizar:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $var)) //$var es la cadena a evaluar y retorna true si lo es
```

Comment: Y sabrás como puedo limitar el numero de caracteres y el código para solo letras? se que es mucho pedir, pero creeme que ya lo he probado de varias maneras

Comment: @WalworthIndustrialdeVlvulas la respuesta fue actualizada.

Comment: No me ha funcionado, creo que mi syntaxis no ha sido buena, habria oporunidad que me pudieras compartir el script completo?